# Ugly effect rotating arcs on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am drawing an arc and pretending that this is rotating. If the arc is small all its OK! but when I Increase it makes a wave effect. If you pay attention you can see a undulation effect.

Would it be possible to correct this issue?

http://jsfiddle.net/vTL3z/2/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var zoom = 5;
var i = 0;
var px = canvas.width/2;
var py = canvas.height/2;
var radio = 80*zoom;
var startSegment, endSegment;

function draw(){
    window.requestAnimFrame(draw);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    startSegment = i*Math.PI;
    endSegment = (i+1.5)*Math.PI;
    i = i + 0.01;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#99FF00';
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.arc(px,py,radio,startSegment,endSegment);
    ctx.stroke();
}


draw();
```

Comment: strange effect, that i see, on OS X 10.9, on Chrome 34., but not on FF 29 or Safari 7. It disappear if you do the arc by hand : http://jsfiddle.net/vTL3z/2/

Comment: This comment is from ferow2k: "Are you testing in Google Chrome?
It seems to have some bugs regarding arcs drawing in canvas: see [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=166876) and [this other](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128330) issue. I tested your fiddle in IE 11 and it worked as expected."

Comment: @Epistemex I can recreate the misbehavior in Chrome but as you say it works without misbehaving in IE (and FF).  Unless you have an idea indicating the OP's code being flawed, ferow2K might have a correct answer: It's a Chrome bug. Any ideas? :-\

Comment: @markE Yeah, I get the issue with Chrome as well. It's a browser issue.

Comment: Seems like an issue with the rounding of the radius. You get a quite similar effect by doing  radio = 80*zoom + 2*Math.random(); before each draw. It is a Chrome bug. It's great Blink will get us a faster Chrome, but bugs/glitches will rain before it becomes stable. This bug : https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-bugs/BwDTm00LzAk is allready logged, best shown here :  http://codepen.io/jcutrell/pen/jhCat/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly a browser issue (<strike>and should be reported to the Chromium team</strike> [Reported here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=166876) and [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-bugs/BwDTm00LzAk). Thanks to @ferow2k and @GameAlchemist for the links).

To get around this you can make your own arc clone:

```
function arc(ctx, x, y, radius, sa, ea) {

    var step = 0.01,
        a = sa + step;

        ctx.moveTo(x + radius * Math.cos(sa),
                   y + radius * Math.sin(sa));

    for(; a < ea; a+=step) {
        ctx.lineTo(x + radius * Math.cos(a),
                   y + radius * Math.sin(a));
    }
}
```

Then use it as:

```
//ctx.arc(px,py,radio,startSegment,endSegment);
arc(ctx, px,py,radio,startSegment,endSegment);
```

The step value can be calculated dynamically using the formula for circle circumference (Øxπ) divided down (to avoid too many overlaps):

```
var steps = radius * Math.PI * 0.25,
    step = Math.PI / steps;
```

I didn't make counter-clock-wise option for it but if you need that you should be able to make that with this as basis.

It will not be as performant as the built-in arc of course (but not bad either). You may have to adjust the step value for an even finer arc if you intend to draw it bigger. At least it will get you around the wobbling arc.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/vncL7/)** and **[FIDDLE (using dynamic step)](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/9ucq7/)**

Comment: as i told in my comments above, https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-bugs/BwDTm00LzAk is the bug allready logged

Comment: Rq : If you want an arc method that works for all circles sizes, then you have to compute step = Math.atan2(1,radius) ;

Comment: You can also draw it once to an off-screen canvas then use rotate transform on our main canvas and draw in the canvas as an image. More memory-hungry but efficient.

Comment: @GameAlchemist thanks, that's a good idea (but the resolution will be overkill for this purpose - a scaling would be necessary). http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/vncL7/1/

Comment: Yes, In fact the formula above is a bit simplified : lw=lineWidth has to be taken into account, and i would use fillRect(,,lw,lw), (faster), not a line. Math.atan(lw,radius) is a better approximation, but anyway, either with line or fillRect, we're only drawing something that looks like an arc, not an arc, so anything good enough/fast enough is... enough ! :-) here http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/vTL3z/7/ uses a step of Math.atan(lw,radius)/lw and seems ok for several radius.

Comment: Second thought : another way to see things, closer to your post, is to consider the 'line resolution' of the arc, meaning the length of a line segment that approximates a part of an arc. The step becomes step = Math.atan2(lineRes, radius).

Comment: I could not understand what I was doing wrong. Excellent solutions, which certainly implementare, while the error is corrected. Thank you.